# How many adjacent appearances of an element in a stack as linked list?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

This is my function; it's supposed to count how many consecutive occurrences of an element in the list.
What it does is count them plus one. Let's say we have 1->1->2->3->NULL; it is supposed to output 2, but it outputs 3.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
void consecutive(node *current) {
    int con=0;
    while (current && current->next) {
        con++;
        if (current->next==NULL)
            break;
        current=current->next;
    }
    cout<<"Number of adjacent appearances is : "<<con<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the current value?  You never examine that.  You are effectively counting the number of elements - 1.

Comment: What is your question? Note that questions are generally indicated by a question mark. You could argue that your subject line contains a question mark but it doesn't contain a verb making it incomplete in a fairly crucial way.

Comment: 42. The answer is always 42.

Comment: Give the definition of node.  I think you are using it wrong based on the common usage of a linked list.

Comment: In the condition of your loop you verify whether `current->next` is non-`NULL` but you never make use of this information. You also break out of the loop if `current->next` is `NULL` but that condition can never hold as you made sure prior to entering the loop that `current->next` is non-`NULL`. It seems you _meant_ to test a member of `current` and `current->next` for being equal but you don't.

Comment: struct node {
 int number;
 node *next; 
};
this is how i defined my node

Comment: Have you tried using the [std::adjacent_find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/adjacent_find/)?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help when you do not provide the struct/class you are using.  If you are looking for consecutive elements with the same value, you could do something like:

```
void consecutive(node *current) {
    int con=0;
    if( current ) {
        auto value = current->number;
        for( current = current->next; current && ( current->number == value ); current = current->next )
            ++con;
    }
    cout<<"Number of adjacent apearances is : "<<con<<endl;
}
```